# Linux command to move files from subfolders into their parent folders

Tags: linux, find, move

i need some help if possible. I need to know how i could find and move all files from subfolders into their parent folders

e.g:

from

```
path/to/folder/x1/xx1/file1
path/to/folder/x2/xx2/file2
```

to

```
path/to/folder/x1/file1
path/to/folder/x2/file2
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to read man pages? https://linux.die.net/man/1/mv

Comment: great question, I don't think mv supports this where the destination parent folder is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this command

```
mv path/to/folder/x1/xx1/file path/to/folder/x1/
```

Comment: yes that worked, but i need to make it happen to multiples folders at once in ```path/to/folder/``` using the ```find``` command..

Answer (score 0):

<sup>If you are looking for a command to **move nested files into a *common* parent folder**, here is an option. Note that this is not what the OP asked.</sup>

This command moves the files in all subfolders of the current folder, starting with `S` and ending in `E` (i.e. matching `S*E`), to the current folder:

```bash
mv ./*/S*E ./
```

For example, to move all `jpg` files in all subfolders to the parent folder, this would be the command:

```bash
mv ./*/*.jpg ./
```

Comment: "into their parent folders"

Comment: You are right about that, however iirc I found this question while I was looking for how to do what I explained. I added a note to my answer. Should I delete it completely? @malhal